# Select dropdown stays over bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, select, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have an input that when changed, there are some validations made and eventually a notification is displayed using a modal.

The problem is that if on the same page there is a select and the input's "onChange" is triggered by clicking on the select, the select's dropdown menu is rendered over the modal and doesn't get "hidden" as it can be seen on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GSqvB/

The HTML code is:

```
<div id="modal-from-dom" class="modal hide fade">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a href="#" class="close">×</a>
        <h3>Modal Heading</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
         <p>One fine body…</p>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
         <a href="#" class="btn primary">Primary</a>
         <a href="#" class="btn secondary">Secondary</a>
     </div>
 </div>

 <span>Write someting then click the select <input type="text" id="inputToChange">     </input></span>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><span>Click me after filling the input <select><option value="1">This</option><option value="2">should</option> <option value="3">be</option><option value="4">hidden</option></select><span>
```

The modal is being launched with this:

```
var $modal = $('#modal-from-dom');
$modal.modal({backdrop: true, keyboard: true, show: false});
$('#inputToChange').on('change', function(event) {
    $modal.modal('show');
});
```

To simulate the behavior you must write something on the input and then click on the select.

If I hide the select and show it when the modal is closed it works, but it seems a really ugly workaround.

Is there a way to make the select "close" or at least to stay behind the modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you show your modal, try hiding & showing the `<select>` element. See this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZTBGA/4/

```
$modal.modal('show');
    $("#input2").hide();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#input2").show();
    }, 5);
```

Edit: *"Is there a way to make the select "close" or at least to stay behind the modal?"*

`.blur()` may work in some browsers, but not Chrome. Solution above will work for all.

Comment: This solves it, although I would prefer something "cleaner", without having to hide and show again the elements. But thanks a lot.